# Regex to avoid specific content

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a string like `23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1+342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1+2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2 + blablabla`.

What I would like to do is to split up the string by `+`, yet in SPK section there is a L+R that would interrupt the process. Is there any REGEX that could achieve what I want?

In result should be:

```
23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1
342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@2
2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2
```

and now what i always get:

```
23DGERA@SPK_20W L
R FA-2@1
342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@2
2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2
```

I'm using Javascript `.split('+')` by now.

Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: Can you share your current regex and specify the environment where you are using the regex please? The code you are using will also help.

Comment: I'm using Javascript .split('+') by now

Comment: Good, so you are using `String#split` without any regex, have you tried any regex yet? Are you targeting any JavaScript environment (including Safari), or do you only target ECMAScript 2018+ compliant ones, that support lookbehinds?

Comment: Also, note it is unclear where `blablabla`  has gone in the results. It is present in the sample string.

Comment: It appears you may wish to split on `+` when preceded and followed by a digit. If so, split on  matches of the regular expression `(?<=\d)\+(?=\d)`, `(?<=\d)` being a *positive lookbehind* and `(?=\d)` being a *positive lookahead*.

Comment: EC6 supports only(so doesnt support lookbehinds i suppose) and for Chrome/Edge, I've tried some regex but all of those are not working. blablabla just means there's more content but I can't paste those confidential content so it is not shown below.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Not necessarily, codes behind + could be like AP3T6000300

Comment: It's rare that a question can be stated unambiguously when expressed in terms of a single example and this one is not an exception. Examples are often helpful for illustration but they are not a substitute for a precise statement of the question in words. I guessed the question was "How do I break a string on plus signs that are both preceded and followed by a digit?". I guessed wrong but you need to provide an equally-precise statement of the problem. In other words, what is the *rule* for determining where to break the string?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the comment. I know the rules are very unclear yet this is all I have for now either. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a matching regex solution:

```js
text.match(/(?:L\+R|[^+])+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m2XoxV/2/). *Details*:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `L\+R` - `L+R` string
  - `|` - or
  - `[^+]` - any char other than `+`
- `)+` - end of the group, one or more occurrences.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var text = '23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1+342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1+2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2';
console.log(text.match(/(?:L\+R|[^+])+/g));
```

*ECMAScript 2018+ compliant solution*

In case you want to migrate to a more modern ECMAScript flavor, you can use

```js
text.split(/\+(?<!L\+(?=R))/)
```

This will match a `+` that is not part of an `L+R` string.

```js
const text = '23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1+342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1+2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2';
console.log(text.split(/\+(?<!L\+(?=R))/));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m2XoxV/3).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting on a `+` you could match the format in the example data.

First match a part containing a single @, and then match till the first occurrence of `@` followed by a digit.

**Note** that the second match will be `342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1` instead of `342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@2`

```
\w+@\w+ [^@]*@\d\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+@\w+` Match 1+ word characters, `@` and at 1+ word characters
- `[^@]*@` Match a space, optional chars other than `@`, then match `@`
- `\d\b` Match a digit and a word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSXB7f/1)

```js
const s = "23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1+342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1+2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2 + blablabla";
const regex = /\w+@\w+ [^@]*@\d\b/g;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Answer (score -1):

The string looks like a list of parts each with a quantity e.g. `@1`. You can use that to identify the correct `+` characters to split on.

Using a look-behind containing `@\d+` -> `(?<=@\d+)` followed by the character you want to match (escaped because `+` has a special meaning) gives:

```
(?<=@\d+)\+
```

Using this in code we also need specify the `g` modifier to match all instances instead of just the first one.

```js
const str =  '23DGERA@SPK_20W L+R FA-2@1+342HSHC@CPU_8PIN INTEL_TEST!@1+2356GHMX@SSD_256G MICRON_CONTENT@2'
const items = str.split(/(?<=@\d+)\+/g);

console.log(items);
```